# UISearchDisplayController TableView goes black after erasing text

Tags: uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that goes black after erasing search-text.

These pictures explain my issue:

Add an a to the searchbar
[image: Add an a to the searchbar]

Removes the a from the searchbar
[image: Removes the a from the searchbar]

I tried these settings in ViewDidLoad, but it's not working.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `searchResultsTableView` is not shown when the search bar is empty. Instead a semi transparent view is shown so that you can see the underlying view (usually the view of the VC that invokes the search). In your case I guess the underlying view is black so it doesn't matter that the search view is semi transparent :)
Setting its background to white color should do the trick.